# Pass C++ class object in lambda capture and convert it to void pointer to pass to a C API

Tags: c++, c, c++11, std-function, stdbind

I am new to functional library. I want to pass lambda to a function that ultimately converts this `std::function<void()>` to a void pointer. I need to pass this void function to a C API. This lambda also takes in the current class object as capture. Here is the code snippet. Any help is appreciated:

```cpp
class Animal{
    public:
        Animal(std::function<void()> func){}

        // call C API that takes in void(*)()
        call_c_api(func); // Somehow convert func to void *
};
class Cat{
    private:
        std::string m_name;
        Animal m_animal;
    public:
        static StaticCatFunc(Cat*instance){
               std::cout << "Name: " << instance->m_name <<"\n";
        }
        Cat(){
           m_animal = new Animal([this](){StaticCatFunc(this);})
        }
};
```

I need to achieve the above functionality. This is not inheritance related question. I need to somehow convert lambda with capture to a void pointer. I have read that lambdas with capture cannot be converted into raw pointers. Is there a way to achieve this functionality? Any help is appreciated.

===========Update=========

c api looks like this:

```cpp
call_c_api(void (*handler)());
```

Comment: That's not possible. You need to erase the capture for it to work. `std::function<void()>` may or may not be `void(*)(void)`: `[]{}` is, `[&]{}` is not.

Comment: Without showing what "`void` pointer conversion" actually means, there is not a lot to tell. Until then the answer is: You can't.

Comment: You need to erase the type and pass a context pointer. For example: `void c_api(void(*callback)(void*), void* context);`. Then in c++, create the context pointer and pass a function pointer to the c api.

Comment: @sturcotte06, can you please explain this more? thanks!

Comment: What will the C API do with the pointer? Will it invoke it as a function? Or will it just store it and pass back to you later?

Comment: @rustyx: It C API will invoke the pointer as a function.

Comment: Ok. Indeed this cannot be done. A `std::function` is a struct, not a function. This is why C APIs normally take a user-defined opaque value to pass to the callback.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that, as `std::function` capture is achieved via type-erasure. It cannot be converted to a C function pointer, unless it has no captured arguments. For this to work, you need to use C-style callback invocations.

```
// In a C header
void c_api(void(*callback)(void*), void* userdata);

// In a C++ header
struct MyStruct {
    MyStruct(std::function<void()> func) {
        _func = std::move(func);
        c_api(&MyStruct::CallbackFromC, this);
    }

    static void CallbackFromC(void* data) {
        MyStruct* self = reinterpret_cast<MyStruct*>(data);
        self->_func();
    }

    std::function<void()> _func;
};
```

It is important to note that MyStruct **MUST** still be a valid pointer when the callback is invoked, or you'll get a SEGFAULT.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the problem is that I do not have access to C source code. I just have the API that can be used.

Comment: @sam91 If the C API does not provide a way for you to pass a user-defined value to the callback, then what you are trying to achieve can't be done directly. It would require storing the `this` pointer in a global (or thread-local) variable, or in a specially-crafted thunk (which requires intimate knowledge of your CPU's architecture, its instruction sets, and assembly programming).

Comment: @sam91 Which C API are you actually using exactly? Not all C APIs use a callback parameter to pass user-defined data, sometimes they have a separate set of functions for that purpose instead, eg: `void callback() { Animal *a = (Animal*) c_api_get_data(); ... }` `c_api_set_data(this); c_api(&callback);`